# Application running in each compute engine instances communicating to one another

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Apart from using Pub/Sub, is there any possible way for application running in each compute engine instances (instance groups) to communicate to each other using the underlying network? If is possible how can i achieve that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances on the same network can communicate to each other using standard TCP/IP protocols provided there is a rule to allow that protocol between the two instances on the [GCE firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) The 'default-allow-all' rule is such a rule created for the default network.

Therefore you can make http requests, have internal APIs and everything you can do over the internet between your compute engine instances. To reference the instances you can use the instance names and in that case the internal DNS metadata server on the project resolves the name to an internal ip address.

For instance groups since the names can change you need to have some sort of mechanism for instances to discover each other names (for example [startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) that writes the created instance name to a file on a bucket).

Comment: thanks for your clear explanation, this have save me from hassle.